# How to access Mapbox layers and subsequent key-value, tags from leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox-gl-js

I am a confused about how to access layers in Mapbox from leaflet.  I have this;

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var map = L.map('map').setView([33.72890830547334, 133.4454345703125], 7);
     
    var osmmapbox = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/usernamexxx/cl6om2qj0003214odo9xx676f/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=[snip]', {
    
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);;
    
    console.log(osmmapbox);
});
```

My mapbox styled map has 2 layers, one of nodes and another of ways.  I tried to look into `osmmapbox` but I cannot see anything.  Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mapbox.js, then you can't. It only supports displaying raster tiles, not interacting  with the data inside vector tiles.

Use Mapbox GL JS if you want to query map data.

Comment: Thank you Steve.  I have moved over to Mapbox GL JS.  Because the dataset is large I have loaded to a dataset and added it to a tile.  Could you please let me know the method to get to layer and say geometry of polygon?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem was more about conceptualization of how mapbox processes info.  What I did was upload my data to a dataset.  I then create a tileset from the dataset.  I created a style but did not include the data in the style but used mapbox gl js to add a geojson with two type of geometries.  This is the final mapbox gl js code;

```
    myToken = '[snip]; 
    mapboxgl.accessToken = myToken;
    
    // add a styled map to the container id map
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container:  'map', // container ID
        style:      'mapbox://[some style link here]',
    });
 
    map.on('load', () => {    
        map.addSource('data-source', {
            type: 'vector',
            // Use any Mapbox-hosted tileset using its tileset id.
            // Learn more about where to find a tileset id:
            // https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/tileset-id/
            url: 'mapbox://[tileset link goes here]'
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'area-polygon',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'data-source',
        'source-layer': 'bicycle_data',       
        'filter': ['==', '$type', 'Polygon']
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'bicycle-parking',
        'type': 'circle',
        'source': 'data-source',
        'source-layer': 'bicycle_data',
        'filter': ['==', '$type', 'Point']
    });
    
});
```